# What does ncp mean on PCA factomine on R?

Tags: r, pca

I want to understand deeply how does the PCA work but I see everywhere this thing
ncp=5 and the only explanation to its meaning I find is #ncp: number of dimensions kept in the result but I do not really understand it well. Lets see if you can help me!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What function are you using exactly? If you have general questions about PCA you are better off asking at [stats.se]. This does not appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I am going to register there and ask. I am using PCA from factominer.